# Word:mac 2008 - Change Path to linked images?

Tags: microsoft-word

I use Word 2008 for Mac and I have a document with linked images. The images are not embedded in the document.
The document and the images are in the same folder but of some reason I had to rename the folder. Now Word is unable to find the images anymore.

How can I fix this without linking to all images again?

Answer (score 0):

You can press ALT+F9 to show field codes. You should see in place of the images a field with brackets and inside some text which points to the folder of your images. You can then go into Find\Replace and enter your old directory path under find and your new directory path under replace. Click "Replace All", close the find dialog and then ALT+F9 once more and all the images should be working!

Comment: too bad the field codes are gone in Office 2011 :-/